# Common encryption and decryption algorithm for Android, iPhone and BlackBerry

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, encryption

I making an application for Android, BlackBerry and iPhone. The application needs to communicate with my Java-based web services. The data should be encrypted when the app and the webservice communicate.

Is there any common algorithm which I can use to encrypt and decrypt the data in these three platforms?  I have searched over the internet but can't find and reliable solution.

Comment: TripleDES can be tried..!! i have tried it for .net and Android!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this would be to use SSL on the web server.  So rather than encrypting the data, encrypt the actual connection.  You'd just connect to 'https://...' rather than 'http://...'.  Thats a very standard encryption that every platform can work with, and you dont have to complicate things in your client apps by encrypting the data.

This of course assumes you control the web server, or otherwise can make sure it has SSL enabled.

Comment: thanks. but web server is not in my control. I can just write the code for both sides to encrypt and decrypt the data

Comment: Thats too bad, because in one simple setting on the web server you could solve the problem across all platforms with no code changes.  Perhaps its something you can bring up with your supervisor (or client).